# Render jqplot chart as image file on server side

Tags: javascript, css, jqplot, server-side

For performance improvement, I would like to render the jqplot chart on the server side by exporting it to an image file for client to download.

I tried the solution using jqplot with node.js but it didn't work. It just gave me  a blank chart as the CSS stylesheet used by jqplot cannot be loaded into the nodejs.

Anybody has successfully made jqplot working with node.js?

Comment: Hi did you find a solution?, was thinking to write a custom npm package for jqplot to get it working on node.